# PATCH vs PUT for Update Bill

Tags: rest, patch, put

We have an inventory feature where we generate Bills. There is a Edit Bill API call. We are confused to implement this as PATCH Or PUT.

let's say our BillLineItem consists of

```
{
   stockId
   quantity
   rate
}
```

A Bill with id = 1 has 2 LineItems :

```
|  Stock Id |   Qty        |  Rate       |
|    10     |      2       |    10       |
|    11     |      3       |    20       |
```

Now lets say I want to change the `quantity for stock Id : 10 to 5` and 
I want to change the `rate for stock Id : 11 to 40`

Should I represent this as **PUT** Call like :

```
bill : {
id : 1

lineItems : [
{
    stockId : 10,
    qty : 5,
    rate : 10   
 },

 {
    stockId : 11,
    qty : 3,
    rate : 40   
 }
]
}
```

Should I represent this as **PATCH** Call like :

```
 bill : {
    id : 1

    lineItems : [
    {
        stockId : 10,
        qty : 5,
     },

     {
        stockId : 11,
        rate : 40   
     }
    ]
    }
```

There are other parameters like discountType, discountValue as part of BillLineItem which I have not shown in the above example.

Comment: As far as the coding is concerned, it makes no difference whether you use PATCH, PUT, or POST. They all just send the data to the server and it can do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: If you're implementing a REST API, PATCH is most appropriate when you're modifying objects rather than replacing them entirely. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods) describes the typical way that HTTP methods correspond to RESTful operations:

> `PUT` - *Replace* all the representations of the member resources of the collection resource with the representation in the request body, or create the collection resource if it does not exist.
>   `PATCH` - *Update* all the representations of the member resources of the collection resource using the instructions in the request body, or *may create* the collection resource if it does not exist.

Since you're updating individual properties of bill items rather than replacing them completely, `PATCH` is the appropriate method.

Answer (score 3):

> We are confused to implement this as PATCH Or PUT.

Both [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) and [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) have remote authoring semantics; loosely, both of these are requests that the server change its copy of a resource to have the same representation as the client's copy.

`PUT` is a direct "make your copy like the copy I've included in this request".  `PATCH` is "apply these changes to your copy".

It follows that `PUT` is [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2); two copies of the same request have the same effect as a single copy of the request.  This semantic hint can be important on an unreliable network -- if a `PUT` request is lost, we can just resend it.  Furthermore, the hint that it is safe to resend the message is both standard and included in the message itself; that means that any *generic* component that sees the message will know that it is safe to resend.

`PATCH` does not have idempotent semantics built into it -- if a message is lost, a generic component does not know whether or not the request can safely be repeated, and therefore it needs to fail, rather than retry.

That's a pretty big win for `PUT` right there.

However, when a resource is very large (meaning, much larger than the HTTP headers), and the size of the change you are making is small, then it may make sense to send only the revisions to the representation, rather than the entire thing.  In that case, using `PATCH` may be a better choice.

Part of the point of REST is that we communicate using "readily standardizable forms", so you should prefer, where possible, to support standardized patch document formats ([application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), or [application/merge-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386)), rather than inventing your own bespoke representation.

Comment: That was very helpful. I shall try to stick to "readily standardizable forms". Thank you for pointing in that direction.