# Case statements for multiple fields when only certain cases exist for each field

Tags: mysql, case

We have an inventory feature where we generate Bills. There is an Edit Bill API call. We have implemented it as PATCH call.

A Bill with id = 1 has 2 LineItems :

```
|  Stock Id |   Qty        |  Rate       |
|    10     |      2       |    10       |
|    11     |      3       |    20       |
```

Now lets say I want to change the `quantity for stock Id : 10 to 5` and I want to change the `rate for stock Id : 11 to 40`

We have represented it as PATCH Call :

```
bill : {
    id : 1

    lineItems : [
    {
        stockId : 10,
        qty : 5,
     },

     {
        stockId : 11,
        rate : 40   
     }
    ]
    }
```

In the backend we run following query :

```
    UPDATE `billlineitem` 
SET    `rate` = ( CASE 
                    WHEN stockid = 11 THEN '40' 
                    ELSE rate 
                  END ), 
       `qty` = ( CASE 
                   WHEN stockid = 10 THEN 5 
                   ELSE qty 
                 END ), 
       `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219' 
WHERE  `bill_id` = '1' 
       AND `stockid` IN ( 10, 11 )
```

Is it ok, in the above case when there is no change for an attribute then the else clause will take the value from the database for that attribute. The above update statement is run in a transaction.

Is this a correct approach? Will this do an update for every attribute for every stock Id. Is there a better approach?

We are using MySQL DB.

Comment: This is the correct way, although you could just do it as separate `UPDATE` queries for each stock ID.

Comment: but if there are 5 - 15 stock Ids --> it might be too many update queries.

Comment: Why would that be too many? But like I said, what you're doing should work fine.

Comment: BTW, you can use `NOW()` for the current time, instead of putting a date and time string.

Comment: I mean 15 update statements in a transaction. Isn't that too much. 
by separate UPDATE queries for each stock ID --> you mean 15 different update statements ?

Comment: The number of queries in a transaction doesn't make any difference. All that matters is how many rows you're updating; whether you do them in one query or 15 doesn't matter.

Comment: I meant one update statement for `stockid = 10`, another for `stockid = 11`, etc. Then you don't need `CASE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written should work, but it will get very complex if you have to update different columns for many different stock IDs. It would probably be simpler, and maybe better performance, to do a separate query for each ID.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE billlineitem 
    SET rate = '40', `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219' 
    WHERE stockid = 10;
UPDATE billlineitem 
    SET qty = 5, `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219'
    WHERE stockid = 11;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. yeah there is a chance that we may be updating different columns for many different stock IDs. For now, we don't expect Vendors to use this method that often if we observe it's being used frequently we shall modify it to individual updates.

Just curious to know, how many updates are safe to run in a transaction.  Let's say if we have 50 different stock Ids --> will your solution still be a good idea?

Comment: There's no specific number as far as I know, it depends on whether those rows will be used by other transactions, since they'll be blocked until the transaction completes. But updating a few hundred rows should not take long, just a second or so.

Comment: can you please check this: 

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816417/patch-vs-put-for-update-bill

Its a question on similar lines.